# Delete Button in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i want a Delete Button in my UITableView like in die AdressBook when editing a contact.

Is this a custom cell, or a UIButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make such button you can do following:

1. Make your `UITableView` style `Grouped`.
2. Add +1 section to your table.
3. Say to your table that it is one cell for last section
4. Just return custom cell (with red background and appropriate label) for last section

Comment: This was my first try, but this looks differnt. No gradient, etc.

Comment: You should add gradient by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the Delegate method's for edit the tableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And than implement the DataSource method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For allowing to get that delete button when you swipe a cell use the

```
Cell Editing Style : UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete
```

// Edit: Wrong answer.
Do you mean the Big one at the bottom or with the sign on the left?

Comment: Have you ever removed contacts?)

Comment: Yes the big one at the bottom

Comment: If you check when the TableView is in edit mode. You can add a subview to the tableview i guess?

Comment: i do not want to add the button, it just need to look like the delete button in the adressbook.

Comment: Than you import the Quartz lib. And use quartz to create a button. Use this: http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/cool-tool-for-quickly-making-glossy-ios-buttons/ or search a tut on quartzcore for creating the glossy button

Answer (score 0):

use....
firstly use

> [btn removeFromSuperview];

and

> [tblobj reload];